# How to show all the html files under a folder with ruby?

Tags: ruby, static

If use this way to show only `index.html` file under `public` folder, it works:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

set :bind, '0.0.0.0'

get '/' do
  File.read('index.html')
end
```

But want to show all files at the current folder, tried below but not work.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

set :bind, '0.0.0.0'

get '/' do
  File.read('*.html')
end
```

Got error:

```
Errno::ENOENT at /
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - *.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to use sinatra for this task, I think that you want some thing simlar to python [simplehttpserver](http://2ality.com/2014/06/simple-http-server.html)

Try with this aproximation:

In a console inside the folder try:

```
 ruby -run -e httpd -- -p 5000

╭─ ~/learn/ruby/ruby-way/stackoverflow/q-static-html-007/html 
╰─ tree
.
.
├── 1.html
└── 2.html
```

[image: server running]

Comment: How to except some files or folders in this way?

Answer (score 3):

Use `Dir.glob('*.html')`.  For example,

```
Dir.glob('*.html'){ |f| File.read f }
```

*NOTE*: `Dir.glob('*.html').each{ }` also works, but `each` is superfluous.

Comment: You don't need to call `each` as `Dir.glob` (optionally) takes a block.

Comment: @cremno Good point, thanks! I've updated the answer accordingly.